# Use of Alternate Entry Points making an Blackberry application can not be uninstalled

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

Im facing an issue when using alternate entry points in blackberry java eclipse.
When iam add the alternate entry point to use push service, the push service is work great, but the application can not be uninstalled. When open Options-> Application Management -> "My App", the delete button is dissapear, only Edit Permissions button is appear.

Iam already trying to remove the alternate entry points in Blackberry_App_Descriptos.xml, and the app can be uninstalled. But now my push service didnt work without that Alternate Entry Points.

Anyone facing the same issue?
Or anyone have some advice to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the solution to this question is a bit weird, but here it is.

If you swap your Application Descriptors around, then the user will be able to uninstall the app. Make the main Application Descriptor the one which has

- Auto-run on startup **checked**
- Do not display the application icon on the BlackBerry home screen **checked**
- no application icon
- the startup argument

then make the alternate entry point the one which has

- Auto-run on startup **unchecked**
- Do not display the application icon on the BlackBerry home screen **unchecked**
- the application icon added
- the gui argument (or in my case no argument)

It seems to me that the alternate entry point is dependant on the original entry point. Therefore if you try and uninstall the main app via the icon, the app that runs at startup will not allow it. Not sure why this happens but there you go

u_u